# Angular: Is the console.log() an object cause the memory leak?

Tags: angular, memory, memory-leaks

As electron angular application increases memory usage over time and I am trying to find the leak. So I studied to debug memory leaks with chrome dev tools and came across this video presentation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr2vrhrNaRo

[image]

I am quite confused about this statement of console log (or debug, info) an object cause memory leak.

As our application dump a lot of log and it seems increasing memory usage. We did need to dump log.

Is there any difference between dumping object or object convert to JSON.stringify(object)? String is also a kind of object, right?

Comment: if console logs were not kept in memory, how would the browser display them, and let you scroll through them?

Comment: @Amadan so if i keep dumping log, then can't avoid memory increasing. then if i don't open dev tools and the apps write log to file, is it also the same behavior? I think console log will have recycle rule if it reached certain usage?

Comment: A browser can't write to files, unless you are making an extension. Console logs are fine if used in development, but should be turned off in production.

Comment: @Amadan Not in browser. It is an electron app.

Comment: I must admit, I forgot :P

Comment: @rodent_la the console keeps the memroy reference to be able to display the object. a production application should not make any console logs.

Comment: for debugging the production application, will dump console.debug log. So just want to avoid memory increasing due to enable debug flag.